# Loop through dictionary with django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

In Django, I have a dictionary, which contains dictionary, example:

```
d['dict1'] = [('1', 'some information'), ('2', 'some information')]
d['dict2'] = [('1', 'some more information'), ('2', 'some more information')]
```

and I need to loop through it, but each time it loops through it only grab the value of dict1 and dict2 corresponding with the loop.counter, so example

```
first time through it would output
1 3
and then
2 4
and so on and so forth
```

I tried doing:

```
{% for item1, item2 in d.items %}
{{ item1.forloop.counter.value1 }}
{{ item2.forloop.counter.value1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

and it produces nothing.

Edit: I updated what the dict actually looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should turn this:

```
d['dict1'] = [('value1', '1'), ('value2', '2')]
d['dict2'] = [('value1', '3'), ('value2', '4')]
```

into this:

```
result = [('value1', '1', '3'), ('value2', '2', '4')]
```

You can do this in your view. You are basically preparing your data to be displayed in the template.

You can then iterate over the values easily:

```
{% for name, v1, v2 in result %}
{{ v1 }}
{{ v2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: okay, but my problem is how I would do that, in my view, it uses a loop to get all the necesary objects and put it in the dictionary(ies)